# How to send two object as response message and response code in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to send response message like this

```
{"message_code": 00, "message": "Success"}
```

My Response Message Class

```
 public class ResponseMessage
 {
    public string MessageCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
 }
```

And my Message Method

```
public ResponseMessage Message(FundTransfer transfer)
{
    var checkBalance = 
    BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetBalance(transfer.FromAccount);

    if (checkBalance.Balance.ToDecimal() < transfer.Amount)
    {
        return new ResponseMessage
        {
            MessageCode = "22",
            Message = "Insufficient Balance"
        };
    }
    else
    {
        var transferData = BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi
            .FundTransfer(transfer);

        if (transferData == true)
        {
            return new ResponseMessage { MessageCode = "00", Message = "Success" };
        }
        else
        {
            return new ResponseMessage { MessageCode = "11", Message = "Some Error" };
        }
    }  
}
```

And my API Method

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("transfer")]
public IHttpActionResult FundTransfer([FromBody] FundTransfer transfer)
{
    var response = Message(transfer);
    if (response.MessageCode == "11")
    {
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        return Ok(response.Message);
    }
}
```

Now for example when the `transferData == true` in my `Message()` Method I get only message object value as "Success" since in my return content I am returning the `response.Message`. I want to get the response in JSON as

```
{"message_code": 00, "message": "Success"}
```

instead of just `"success"`

Currently learning Web API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactor API Method to return model instead of just the message property

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("transfer")]
public IHttpActionResult FundTransfer([FromBody] FundTransfer transfer) {
    var response = Message(transfer);
    if (response.MessageCode == "11") {
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response);
    } else {
        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

Also to get message like this

```
{"message_code": "00", "message": "Success"}
```

Refactor `ResponseMessage` class via JSON property attribute...

```
 public class ResponseMessage {
    [JsonProperty("message_code")]
    public string MessageCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
 }
```

Or construct model anonymously

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("transfer")]
public IHttpActionResult FundTransfer([FromBody] FundTransfer transfer) {
    var response = Message(transfer);
    var model = new {
        message_code = response.MessageCode,
        message = response.Message
    };
    if (response.MessageCode == "11") {
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, model);
    } else {
        return Ok(model);
    }
}
```